# How to get the estimated time while loading spark dataframe to database

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark, jdbc

I am using spark to write a dataframe to database, but i also want to know the progress of data load in percentage form.

So is there any way through which i can get the estimated time or progress of dataframe write to the database

Comment: you can look at the spark ui web page to view the job status

Comment: Thanks Binzi for your quick response, but i want to get the output in my code result

Comment: You can use any of Spark's monitoring and instrumentation methods https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/monitoring.html